# Can i verify downloaded file in browser stack using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I am automating with browser stack. I am downloading the file in browser stack using selenium, but I want verify the downloaded file. Can I do this using selenium.(Upon downloading the file, file will be browser stack server's folders, i need to verify that file has downloaded or not).

Answer (score 0):

In selenium you can have a problem with this.
I'm using java script command where I'm checking the file is empty or not.
It's checking response header when you clicking

```
object response = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.WebDriver).ExecuteAsyncScript(
                "var url = arguments[0];" +
                "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
                "xhr.open('GET', url, true);" +
                "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
                "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {" +
                "    callback(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());" +
                "  }" +
                "};" +
                "xhr.send();", url);

            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
```

In response header is information about "Content-Length:" and I'm looking for this key and I'm checking there is enough length.